# MediatR share TableBatchOperation for transactional save in different handler

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage, cqrs, mediatr

I search how I can share an TableBatchOperation Azure table storage between multiple Handler, for make an transactional behavior.

In CQRS scenario I would make multiple insert in Azure Table Storage but with the bus memory like MediatR it's difficult if this inserts are in different handler, if one failed but not the other.

I think it's ok if I share an TableBatchOperation before and after the publish() call method.

There are an recommandation for do this ?

Answer (score 1):

The general rule of CQRS is that each command is handled in a separate transaction. If you want multiple commands to be handled inside one transaction, you either need to send one command for the whole batch, or you need to look at saga/courier patterns.